# Когда пытаюсь загрузить изображение, то получаю статус код 400

Tags: asp, blazor-server-side

Скачал Blazor.Radzen. Мне в нем нужен был HtmlEditor.
Проблема в том, что когда пытаюсь загрузить изображение, то получаю статус код 400. Добавление по ссылке работает.

[Создал чистый проект для просмотра исходников](https://github.com/BCEBOLOD/ForProblem/tree/master/ForProblem).

Возможно, что я не всё подключил, но понять не могу что именно.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если подскажете замену Radzen с html Editor где изображение загружается на сервер, а не base64, то буду рад.
Также,очень буду рад,если датите ссылку на проект где смогу посмотреть реализацию всю и найти ошибку сам

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мне ответил сам разработчик Radzen

> Похоже, в вашем приложении не полностью включена поддержка
> контроллеров MVC. Вам нужна эта строка в вашем Program.cs
>
> `app.MapControllers();` Вы можете поместить его непосредственно перед
> app.Run();